# Given common terms (and their position) between an arithmetic and geometric sequences, find the common ratio.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The fourth, seventh and sixteenth terms of an arithmetic sequence also form consecutive terms of a geometric sequence. Find the common ratio of the geometric sequence

Answer (score 2):

Let the three terms be 'x', 'y' and 'z'. Let 'd' be common difference and 'r' be common ratio.

The terms of the arithmetic sequence would be:

Term 4 of arithmetic sequence ---> $x = a + 3d$

Term 7 of arithmetic sequence ---> $y = x + 3d$

Term 16 of arithmetic sequence ---> $z = y + 9d$

Term 1 of geometric sequence ---> $x$

Term 2 of geometric sequence ---> $y = xr$

Term 3 of geometric sequence ---> $z = xr^2$

(1) $xr^2 = xr + 9d$

(2) $xr = x + 3d$

Multiply (2) by 3, giving: $3xr = 3x + 9d$

Subtract the two equations, giving:

$r^2 - 4r + 3 = 0$

$(r-3)(r-1)=0$

$r = 3$ or $r = 1$

Comment: One might suggest that $r=1,d=0$ giving a constant sequence is contrary to the spirit of the problem and we should only accept $r=3, d=\frac {2x}3$.  Well done.